# Selenium side runner + chromedriver tests with docker not running

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get selenium side runner to run some tests using docker, to include in our CI.

I am able to run the tests locally in my machine by running:

`selenium-side-runner C:\path-to-tests\tests-selenium.side`

This is windows host.

I am trying to do the same using docker locally, so afterwards I will migrate this to our Teamcity.

First I am running the selenium server container:

`docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --name chromedriver selenium/standalone-chrome:3.4.0`

Afterwards I run the selenium side runner container:

`docker run -v C:\path-to-tests:/sides --link chromedriver:chromedriver nixel2007/docker-selenium-side-runner`

I have to link the containers otherwise I get an error saying that the container can't connect to chromedriver:4444

I also have to mount the volume where my tests are.

When I do this and run, I get the following error:

```
Test suite failed to run

WebDriverError: Unable to parse new session response
```

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE:**

I also tried different versions of the `selenium/standalone-chrome` container, `selenium/standalone-chrome:3.4.0`, `selenium/standalone-chrome:3.141.59-xenon` and `selenium/standalone-chrome:latest`

All fail with different errors.

**SECOND UPDATE:**

I have been able to get the tests to run, both locally and in teamcity. One of the issues that I am facing right now is that docker-compose seems to hang. Not sure if this is container related, or docker-compose related.

When I run the tests, the selenium side runner container exits with code 1 and I do not get back to the host console prompt, it stays forever waiting for something to happen.

The error is this:
`selenium_selenium-side-runner_1 exited with code 1`

I have gotten the docker-compose file from here:
https://github.com/nixel2007/docker-selenium-side-runner/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Any clues on what I might be missing?

Comment: Any specific reason to choose this docker image "selenium/standalone-chrome:3.4.0" . seems this is an issue of compatibility between chrome image used and selenium-side-runner

Comment: @Ishan I tried selenium/standalone-chrome:3.4.0, selenium/standalone-chrome:3.141.59-xenon and selenium/standalone-chrome:latest. all of them fail with different errors.

Comment: @BlunT I hope you had some progress with this.
I'm interested in doing the same, but I haven't found a nice article/tutorial.
Do you have any updates?
Thanks

Comment: @FC.Araujo yes, I will update the question. I have moved forward, but I haven't found a solution yet.